# how to make a soundcloud widget?

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget, soundcloud

So I have been looking to make a Sound Cloud widget for code-pen for testing then I will implement it to my website. what I am trying to aim for is something that displays a couple of tabs that you can click on that will let you change the view to different parts of my profile such as my re-posts and my tracks that is all I want but my problem is that i do not know how to code at all I have looked at the soundcloud resources:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget

but it is all confusing as I have no idea what to start with as a base and what I need. I have looked for templates but found nothing that matches my keywords.

for now all I am trying to do is create a widget that matches this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H2rE.png)

using css js and html and any other code that can be embedded in html 
I also want to make it possible for anyone to modify it for their own account by a variable at the top of the JavaScript code for the key, a commented out link to get a consumer key and any other key that is related/required for the widget, the user id / user URL, how to find the user id with link.
for now those are not required because getting a working widget is my first priority even if it does not look good. so I am asking for help on what I NEED to do first to get a base to it for example what lines do I need in my html to import the SDK for the widget? what are the requirements do I need for my widget such as a API key and what one because I know you can enable certain things with api's and disable options such as playback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Make the href="www.example.soundcloud.com/user/re-posts" for each tab, I am unfamiliar with soundcloud API's though

Comment: thank you I will do that over the image I got. although I guess I could do that instead of using a API